# RubyMine - How do I Debug Cucumber Step files?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rubymine

RubyMine - How do I Debug Cucumber Step files?  I have googled this a a bit and any information I have found has not worked for me.  Has anyone got step files to debug when using RubyMine?

Thanks

Comment: [Works out of the box](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/2456/20130226141046.png). What specific problems do you have? Note that you can't debug feature files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horrendously common problem with many, many failed solutions online.  You don't need any new gems, no need to change settings.

Quite likely, you have all your feature files in the root folder.

It sounds ridiculous, but make a new folder, places the feature files in there (call it something generic like "tests").

Set a breakpoint, and try again.  This should remedy it.

Answer (score 1):

Add 'pry' to your Gemfile

require 'pry' (up near the top, or in your startup/hooks)

In the step you want to debug, at the point you're having trouble with:
binding.pry

This dumps you into a REPL where you can examine all the local variables etc.  If you're interacting with a browser using selenium you can also look at the browser, use 'inspect element', then see if you can find the element with the selenium calls.

You can also make a step (mine is called 'And I debug') which does nothing but call binding.pry; this is useful if you just want to stop the selenium automation temporarily.  To exit the REPL, use 'exit' or ^D.

You will have to run your cukes from the command line to use this effectively; not sure what features rubymine has for that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i did not have the 'debugger' gem in the proper group in the Gemfile

Make sure:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'debugger'
end
```

**The debugger gem is no longer recommended, try [debugger2](https://github.com/ko1/debugger2) instead.**

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following as the contents of features/support/debugging.rb can be helpful in debugging failing steps:

```
# `LAUNCHY=1 cucumber` to open page on failure
After do |scenario|
  save_and_open_page if scenario.failed? && ENV['LAUNCHY']
end

# `FAST=1 cucumber` to stop on first failure
After do |scenario|
  Cucumber.wants_to_quit = ENV['FAST'] && scenario.failed?
end

# `DEBUG=1 cucumber` to drop into debugger on failure
After do |scenario|
  next unless ENV['DEBUG'] && scenario.failed?
  puts "Debugging scenario: #{scenario.title}"
  if respond_to? :debugger
    debugger
  elsif binding.respond_to? :pry
    binding.pry
  else
    puts "Can't find debugger or pry to debug"
  end 
end

# `STEP=1 cucumber` to pause after each step
AfterStep do |scenario|
  next unless ENV['STEP']
  unless defined?(@counter)
    puts "Stepping through #{scenario.title}"
    @counter = 0
  end
  @counter += 1
  print "At step ##{@counter} of #{scenario.steps.count}. Press Return to"\
        ' execute...'
  STDIN.getc
end
```

By setting an environment variable, you can cause Cucumber to use various debugging tools, and you can combine them by setting multiple environment variables.

Answer (score -1):

Not RubyMine, but if you are comfortable with CLI the **debugger** gem helps a lot

`[sudo] gem install debugger`

Then place the keyword **debugger** before the LOC in question and run cucumber as normal. The **debugger** will stop right before the LOC that you have an issue with.

I use this to step through issues with Cucumber/WATIR all the time.

https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger

Comment: What is LOC? I place `debugger` inside my step definition but the execution isn't stopped.